# CentOS memory allocation

Tags: centos, memory

I was running my VPS with CentOS on 1G memory, but I saw the memory was getting "full" so I had 1G extra installed.

This VPS is one I rent at a hosting company.
That company did most of the configuration for me on installation of the VPS.
They also installed DirectAdmin and handled all domain/DNS issues.

I only installed certain user/FTP accounts and uploaded all my production websites.
This servers hosts:
5 small static PHP websites, 2 wordpress websites, 1 Magento webshop, a testing evirment for myself and all e-mail accounts for each website.

My goal is to enhance the server performance.

I looked at various of guides on the internet.
I broke allot of things and had to fix them afterwards, so I learned as I was going.
I found out that I need to follow some correct guides/tutorials and need to make sure to follow only CentOs related stuff.

`ulimit -a` and `free -m` command tell the following:

```
[root@1332 etc]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 32365
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 32365
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
[root@1332 etc]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2026        990       1036          0        129        620
-/+ buffers/cache:        240       1786
Swap:         2047          0       2047
```

So I have some extra free memory

```
top - 14:35:36 up  4:15,  1 user,  load average: 0.57, 0.49, 0.46
Tasks: 169 total,   1 running, 168 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.1%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2075000k total,  1016716k used,  1058284k free,   133924k buffers
Swap:  2097144k total,        0k used,  2097144k free,   637168k cached
```

I did a restart of the server, thats probably why everything is looking great.

I changed `my.cnf` settings to the following:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
skip-locking
query_cache_limit=2M
query_cache_size=64M
query_cache_type=1
max_connections=500
interactive_timeout=100
wait_timeout=120
connect_timeout=10
thread_cache_size=128
key_buffer=384M
join_buffer=8M
max_allowed_packet=16M
table_cache=1024
record_buffer=1M
sort_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=2M
max_connect_errors=10
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency=6
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
server-id=1

[safe_mysqld]
err-log=/var/log/mysqld.log
open_files_limit=8192

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer=64M
sort_buffer=64M
read_buffer=16M
write_buffer=16M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=64M
sort_buffer=64M
read_buffer=16M
write_buffer=16M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

I noticed that I don't have any `innoDB` settings here.
Probably because they aren't installed or because of the presence of DirectAdmin or because my hoster doesn't use that.

So, some questions:

1. Are my.cnf settings "correct" for having the best settings? (at this moment)
2. Are there any other settings I need to worry about?
3. Are there any performance tweaks I still need to do for Magento? (I tried installing APC or Xcache, but that didn't do much)
4. I installed REDIS, but is it normal that I don't "feel" anything in performance because of that?

Comment: what's the point of innoDB it is a mysql database ?
Please precise what your server usage...

Comment: Dont you need the innoDB settings for MySQL performance? This server is used to host a Magento webshop

Comment: if innoDB is not install, it's not part of standard mysql db engine, so if you do not install it, it's not there. And you're post does not tell a world about server usage.

Comment: hence I'm here asking for help...

Comment: yes I know, but if you want to maximize you're chance of getting help, try to be the more precise possible. A well prepared  question can gets lots of answer very fast. Concerning your problem I can't tell you if it's normal not to have a innoDB parameter, but try to chack if your mysql installation provide innoDB or not. beacause this is not mandatory.

Comment: I want to have the best performance for that Magento shop, therefor I'm looking for the "best" settings needed. But, I don't really know where to look other then Google. So, I end up looking for things I don't even understand. It is very difficult to explain stuff u don't understand and write a question about it.

Comment: Yes it is. I can't help you with you're problem but First maybe is trying to get yourself some documentation. Because imagine how hard it is for someone that do not know your problem to understand a problem you  can't even formualted. What I can advise you is to edit your post to make it more clear about your final goal.  
And finally please do not try to run a production web shop without more knownledge ;-)

Comment: I edited my question. Where do I get this knowledge? Other then reading CentOS command documentation or following tutorials...

Comment: experience and training...
and in the magento forum or wiki, because your problem is not really a centos issue...

Comment: I did, the [magento wiki](http://www.mgt-commerce.com/blog/magento-on-steroids-best-practice-for-highest-performance/) doesn't help me